# jQuery functions work in one aspx but don't work in another aspx that's practically identical

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my MasterPage.master page I have this two jquery functions:

```
function calcTime() {
    var time1 = $(".timepickerFrom").val().split(':'),
      time2 = $(".timepickerTo").val().split(':');
    var hours1 = parseInt(time1[0], 10),
      mins1 = parseInt(time1[1], 10),
      hours2 = parseInt(time2[0], 10),
      mins2 = parseInt(time2[1], 10),
      time = "";

    var diff = 0,
      hours = 0,
      mins = 0;

    mins1 = (hours1 * 60) + mins1;
    mins2 = (hours2 * 60) + mins2;
    diff = mins2 - mins1;
    if (diff < 0) {
        diff = 1440 + diff;
        document.getElementById('labelTime').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('labelTime').style.display = 'none';
    }

    hours = Math.floor((diff / 60), 0);
    mins = Math.round((((diff / 60) - hours) * 60), 0);
    time = hours + ":" + Right("00" + mins, 2);

    if (time == "NaN:aN") {
        time = "0:00";
    }

    $(".timepickerTime").val(time);
};

function calcTo() {
    var time1 = $(".timepickerFrom").val().split(':'),
      time2 = $(".timepickerTime").val().split(':');
    var hours1 = parseInt(time1[0], 10),
      mins1 = parseInt(time1[1], 10),
      hours2 = parseInt(time2[0], 10),
      mins2 = parseInt(time2[1], 10),
      time = "";

    var diff = 0,
      hours = 0,
      mins = 0;

    mins1 = (hours1 * 60) + mins1;
    mins2 = (hours2 * 60) + mins2;
    diff = mins1 + mins2;

    if (diff >= 1440) {
        diff = diff - 1440;
        document.getElementById('labelTime').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('labelTime').style.display = 'none';
    }

    hours = Math.floor(diff / 60, 0);
    mins = Math.round(((diff / 60) - hours) * 60, 0);
    time = hours + ":" + Right("00" + mins, 2);

    if (time == "NaN:aN") {
        time = "0:00";
    }

    $(".timepickerTo").val(time);
};
```

both are working fine.

then I have one page: NewRecord.aspx which have these lines of code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">Čas od </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-10 col-sm-5">
            <input id="timepickerFrom" name="timepickerFrom" type="text" class="form-control timepickerFrom" value="<%= this.InputValue_timepickerFrom %>" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-110"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">Čas do </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-10 col-sm-5">
            <input id="timepickerTo" name="timepickerTo" type="text" class="form-control timepickerTo" value="<%= this.InputValue_timepickerTo %>" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-110"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">Čas skupaj </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-10 col-sm-5">
            <input id="timepickerTime" name="timepickerTime" type="text" class="form-control timepickerTime" value="<%= this.InputValue_timepickerTime %>" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-110"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label id="labelTime" style="display: none; color: red">Pozor! Čas do je manjši od časa od.</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and calculations are working fine. When I change from or to it recalculates time and when I change time it recalculates to.

then I have one more file: VacationNewRecord.aspx
An in it code like this:

```
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-10 col-sm-5">
            <input id="timepickerFrom" name="timepickerFrom" type="text" class="form-control timepickerFrom" value="<%= this.InputValue_timepickerFrom %>" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-110"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group hidden" id="cas2" runat="server">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">Čas do </label>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-10 col-sm-5">
            <input id="timepickerTo" name="timepickerTo" type="text" class="form-control timepickerTo" value="<%= this.InputValue_timepickerTo %>" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-110"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group hidden" id="cas3" runat="server">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">Čas skupaj </label>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-10 col-sm-5">
            <input id="timepickerTime" name="timepickerTime" type="text" class="form-control timepickerTime" value="<%= this.InputValue_timepickerTime %>" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-110"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here how functions are called:

```
     $('.timepickerFrom').timepicker({
        minuteStep: 15,
        showSeconds: false,
        showMeridian: false,
        disableFocus: true,
        appendWidgetTo: "body",
        icons: {
            up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
            down: 'fa fa-chevron-down'
        }
    }).on('change', function () {
        calcTime();
    }).next().on(ace.click_event, function () {
        $(this).prev().focus();
    });

    $('.timepickerTo').timepicker({
        minuteStep: 15,
        showSeconds: false,
        showMeridian: false,
        disableFocus: true,
        icons: {
            up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
            down: 'fa fa-chevron-down'
        }
    }).on('change', function () {
        calcTime();
    }).on('focus', function () {
        $('#timepickerTo').timepicker('showWidget');
    }).next().on(ace.click_event, function () {
        $(this).prev().focus();
    });

    $('.timepickerTime').timepicker({
        minuteStep: 15,
        showSeconds: false,
        showMeridian: false,
        disableFocus: true,
        icons: {
            up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
            down: 'fa fa-chevron-down'
        }
    }).on('change', function () {
        calcTo();
    }).on('focus', function () {
        $('#timepickerTime').timepicker('showWidget');
    }).next().on(ace.click_event, function () {
        $(this).prev().focus();
    });
```

Code in both files is practically identical. I use class selector. so why the code in first aspx works fine and in the second works only when I change time?

Comment: how are calcTime() and calcTo() being called? There's nothing in either snippet to indicate how they are triggered

Comment: Try to use Firebug and see if there's any error.

Comment: i have added. function are caller on change event.

Comment: i'm getting this error on the second aspx "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Comment: oh.. i was missing <label id="labelTime"> in the second aspx. tnx ekad!